# Do we really need to implement Auth::attempt() in laravel in order to authenticate a user?

Tags: laravel-5

Hi this question is related to PHP Laravel Framework. Do we really need to implement `Auth::attempt()` in laravel in order to authenticate a user? If we manually code it like below what will be the disadvantages? Are there any outstanding benefits of using `Auth::attempt()`?

eg code for manually authentication:

```
$member = Member::where('email', $username_email)
    ->orwhere('username', $username_email)->first();

if ($member) {
    if (Hash::check($password, $member->getPassword())) {
        //login success code
    } else {
        //login fail code
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Auth:attempt()` is not all about password validation, it will also puts logged user object to the session, so we can access it through methods of the `Auth` class like `Auth::user()` and `Auth::id()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You mean, by using this Auth, we can manage sessions as well and get all the benefits of it. So What if we write manually? Also get the same benefit...isn't it? Are there any remarkable benefits like security...